# Fetch the contents of the cell, based on the match within the cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please help me in this case . I tried searching for answers. #noviceinexcel
A1 = HasHasOneApple (or) HeHasTwoOrange

A2 should fetch 6th to last character of A1, when the 6th to 8th contains One
A3 should fetch 6th to last character of A1, when the 6th to 8th contains Two

A2 = OneApple
A3 = TwoOrange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In A2: `= IF( MID( A1, 7, 3 ) = "one", RIGHT( A1, LEN( A1 ) - 6 ), "" )`

In A3: `= IF( MID( A1, 7, 3 ) = "two", RIGHT( A1, LEN( A1 ) - 6 ), "" )`

Comment: Thanks @NiH. this worked. I replaced the semicolon with a comma.